# Stop Excel recognizing a dash

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I stop my text cells which start with a dash from turning into cells where Excel expects a formula?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

comment it using the single quote

e.g.

```
'-A10
```

will display `-A10` in excel instead of it being misinterpreted as formula.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any option to turn it off though so I don't have to keep using a single quote?

Comment: Maybe you can set the cell formatting to text/string before entering text.

Comment: Preceding it by a space seems to be the easiest solution for me. Thanks everyone....

Answer (score 4):

Use the 'find and replace' tool in excel. Find '=' and replace with nothing, i.e. an empty space. Then click on 'replace all.

Comment: Read over https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and then you can start commenting once you get there.