# How to prevent Excel from inserting formulas when typing + or - at the beginning of a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection

Sometimes I have to mark some cells in a spreadsheet with `-` to indicate that it was not available or not related, not tested... Sometimes I also use `+` to denote positiveness or availability.

But after pressing <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> key in an empty cell and press arrow keys or click mouse button to proceed to the next cell like I usually do, it automatically *selects the other cell* in the formula. So I have to quit editing and type the text again. This is very annoying.

I never start a formula with `+` or `-` but always use `=`. So how can I turn off this behavior? Using macro is also fine.

Comment: [How to force excel to stop thinking your cell contains a formula](http://superuser.com/q/792134/241386)

Comment: Tons of similar questions but all the solutions are putting `'` at the beginning which I already used for over a decade and is not what I wanted [Stop Excel recognizing a dash](http://superuser.com/q/224983/241386), [How to tell Excel not to evaluate a formula?](http://superuser.com/q/641248/241386)

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest typing an apostrophe `'` before typing the plus or minus. This will escape that functionality and disappear once you move on.

Comment: I already know that for years, but this is not a solution, since it requires 2 keystrokes while + and - can already be at the beginning of the cell without escaping

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you didn't specify what version of excel, but you could try pre-formatting the cells to "text" - though it doesn't work for me

Comment: I've tried that on both excel 2007 and 2010 and it doesn't work

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: It looks like you are choosing to use a scheme that Excel interprets in a different way by default.  The easy solution is to use a method that is consistent with how Excel is designed to work.  One extra keystroke is a small price to pay.  How much more time/work is that than using a multi-key macro?

Comment: @fixer1234 a macro is a permanent solution

Comment: I know of no setting to disable this behavior with `-` and `+`, and no way to intercept keystrokes at the time of formula entry in the way you're seeking.  Event macros such as `Worksheet_Change` only fire when you finish editing a formula, but the problem is that Excel enters formula entry mode instead of value entry mode on the 'application level' when it sees `=`, `+` or `-` as the first character entered. I believe there is no VBA 'hook' for macros to grab hold of to alter the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to disable the automatic formula function is to reformat the sheet (or individual rows, columns, or cells, as suits your need) as Text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AutoCorrect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AutoCorrect-spelling-and-insert-text-and-symbols-e7433b94-f3de-4532-9dc8-b29063a96e1f) feature of Office to replace other arbitrary characters of your choice with `+` or `-`.

Note that AutoCorrect list is shared between all Office applications so this approach may have unintended consequences. Choose your characters to replace wisely.

Answer (score 0):

As commented already, even with a macro it's not possible to prevent excel from starting a formula.
If you really want one keystroke and leave the cell then you need to change from + and - characters e.g. to "p" and "n" and you get get a macro which change them to your desired output when you finishing editing of cell content. 
Other workaround could be to type 0 and 1 and change them with conditional formatting.

Comment: What do you mean by defined in the format? You don't type them but the macro runs immediately when you changed your cell content and you will have them.

Comment: ok I misread your solution